# Jni4net with Java 11

Tags: jni4net

I am using the jni4net to bridge a .net dll to java. It is working fine with in the Java8 environment. Unfortunately, with java 8 I am getting the following error:

I have tried to compile generated jvm  with java-11, but still the same problem.

```
Can't bind bridge:Can't initialize proxy java.lang.System
Can't bind bridge:net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: Can't initialize proxy 
java.lang.System ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein 
Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> java.lang.LinkageError: 
runFinalizersOnExit
bei net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIEnv.ExceptionTest()
bei net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID(Class clazz, String name, 
String sig)
bei java.lang.System.InitJNI(JNIEnv __env, Class __class)
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] 
arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, 
Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags 
invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
bei System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterStaticAndMethods(RegistryRecord 
record, JNIEnv env)
--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterStaticAndMethods(RegistryRecord 
record, JNIEnv env)
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.BindJvm(RegistryRecord record, ClassLoader 
classLoader, JNIEnv env)
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.BindJvm(RegistryRecord record, JNIEnv env)
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterType(Type type, Boolean bindJVM, 
JNIEnv env)
bei net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly, 
Boolean bindJVM)
bei net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
bei net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.BindCore(JNIEnv env, BridgeSetup newSetup)
bei net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.initDotNetImpl(IntPtr envi, IntPtr clazz)
Can't initialize jni4net BridgeC
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to compile and execute the same with **java 11**.

Try downloading the [JNI4NET](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n1QpKzaXXLQDpKXmhBfsBFxbwAxsKZej/view?usp=sharing) libs inside your project.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution you can use `ProcessBuilder` and define in it environment the `JAVA_HOME` variable with the path to java 8.